# Small question about integral

Tags: integration, analysis

can i do something to this integral 
$$\int_t^{+\infty}\frac{1}{p(s)}\left[\int_s^{+\infty} q(\xi)u_2(\xi) d\xi -\frac{1}{||\frac1p||}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{p(s)}[\int_s^{+\infty} q(\xi)u_2(\xi) d\xi]ds\right]ds$$
where $p,q>0$ and $\frac1p, \frac1q \in L^1((0,+\infty))$

Thank you

Comment: i edited my message

Comment: As an aside: it is sort-of odd to be using $s$ as the "dummy" variable in two nested integrals.  It's OK in this situation (because it can be easily figured out), but it can cause difficulty for other problems.

Comment: i don't understand what i must do ?

Comment: Since $s$ is used as the variable of integration for the outer integral, it should not also be used as the variable of integration for an integral nested inside that one (the problem @anorton feels "can be easily figured out").

Comment: @hardmath At second glance, I realize I was making a (possibly unwarranted) assumption to "easily figure out" difficulty.  I agree that the second $s$ should really be changed.

Comment: @anorton: I have confidence in your ability to sort it out in a meaningful way.  It's a bit delicate to be sure editing a Question doesn't change the intended meaning (esp. since $s$ also appears as a limit of integration), so I'm hoping you've inspired Vrouvrou to make the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{||1/p||}\int_t^{\infty}\frac{1}{p(s)}\left[||\frac{1}{p}||\int_s^{\infty}q(\xi)u_2(\xi)d\xi-\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{p(u)}\int_u^{\infty}q(\xi)u_2(\xi)d\xi du\right]ds\\
=\frac{1}{||1/p||}\int_t^{\infty}\frac{1}{p(s)}\left[\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{p(u)}du\int_s^{\infty}q(\xi)u_2(\xi)d\xi-\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{p(u)}\int_u^{\infty}q(\xi)u_2(\xi)d\xi du\right]ds\\
=\frac{1}{||1/p||}\int_t^{\infty}\frac{1}{p(s)}\left[\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{p(u)}\int_s^uq(\xi)u_2(\xi)d\xi du\right]ds$$
Let $Q(s)=\int_0^sq(\xi)u_2(\xi)d\xi$ and $R(t)=\int_t^{\infty}\frac{Q(s)}{p(s)}ds$
Then your integral becomes
$$\frac{1}{||1/p||}\int_t^{\infty}\frac{1}{p(s)}\left[\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{p(u)}(Q(u)-Q(s))du\right]ds\\=\frac{R(0)}{||1/p||}\int_t^{\infty}\frac{1}{p(s)}ds-R(t)$$

Comment: Thanks, that's an improvement.

Comment: i don't understand how to find the step 3

Comment: @hardmath please how we past from the step 2 to the step 3

Comment: Both terms have $1/p(u)$, and $q(\xi)u_2(\xi)$.  The only difference is the limit of the integral.  So the difference between the terms is the integral over the gap from $s$ to $u$.

Comment: but $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{du}{p(u)}\int_s^{+\infty}q(\xi) u_2(\xi) d\xi \neq \int _0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{p(u)}\int_s^{+\infty} q(\xi)u_2(\xi) d\xi du$

Comment: Why not? the $\xi$ integral is a constant as far as $u$ is concerned, so I brought it inside the $u$ integral.  I think.

Comment: This seems okay to me, the integrand in the first factor depends only on $u$, and the integrand in the second factor depends only on  $\xi$, and the limits of integration depend on neither $u$ nor $\xi$.